# py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist when pass class method to map in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a rdd in a class, and I defined the map function as class method, when I pass the map function to pyspark map, it raised an error:`py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist`, my code:

```
class A(object):
def __init__(self):
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("A")
    self.spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

def f(self):
    mapper = self.mapper
    rdds = self.spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
    print(rdds.map(mapper).collect())

# @staticmethod
def mapper(self, row):
    s = []
    for i in range(5):
        if row == 1:
            if len(s) >= 2:
                break
        if row == 2:
            if len(s) >= 3:
                break
        s.append(row)
    return s
```

Someone say the self cannot pass to workers, so I use `mapper = self.mapper`, but it still not work, How can I deal with it except adding staticmethod decorator to mapper?